# Should the links on ServiceStack metadata page be encoded?

Tags: servicestack, owasp

A scanner tool we use is reporting a security concern. It monitored the response from `GET /metadata` within `ServiceStack.Metadata.IndexOperationsControl.Render()` and reported a response without validation or encoding. Specifically, complaining about the URL. Here is the snippet it is concerned about:

```
<h3>Plugin Links:</h3><ul><li><a href="https://mysitedomain/swagger-ui/">Swagger UI</a></li></ul> </div> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I might be generalizing too much. It looks like the issue is that ultimately, ServiceStack calls `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.Write()` instead of `System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.WriteEncodedText()` for the plug in links here

```
            var pluginLinks = metadata != null && metadata.PluginLinks.Count > 0
            ? new ListTemplate
            {
                Title = metadata.PluginLinksTitle,
                ListItemsMap = ToAbsoluteUrls(metadata.PluginLinks),
                ListItemTemplate = @"<li><a href=""{0}"">{1}</a></li>"
            }.ToString()
            : "";
```

Should the URL be encoded right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no security concern, the links on the metadata pages are defined by Plugins that are statically known at compile time, i.e. they never embed unknown user-defined links.